# Calculating image means channel-wise and pixel-wise

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am kind of stuck trying to figure out the difference between channel-wise means and pixel-wise means. I know channel-wise means return an MxN matrix but the maths/process keeps fading from me

An explanation would be helpful.

You can refer to the post I originally found it - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/06/deep-learning-opencvs-blobfromimage-works/

Answer (score 1):

your original post does no more exist, but since it was about cnn's ... :

ppl often *normalize* the input (e.g. an image) by:

- subtracting the mean value
- dividing by variance

so, in opencv speak, the difference would be:

```
// channel-wise mean, the same number for all pixels:
img -= Scalar(127,124,122);

// pixel-wise mean, a different value for each pixel:
img -= mean_img;
```

as an example, here's the mean image for the LFW database:

[image]

Comment: The example for the channel-wise explanation, does it mean 127 is the mean of the blue channel, 124 (Green channel) and 122 (R channel)?